# HTML Canvas Function

Tags: javascript, canvas

I have been writing some HTML canvas code in order to make a landscape. The code will not execute properly. What is my syntax error? Thanks, Benjamin

```
var canvas = document.getElementById("mycanvas");
var ctx = canvas.getContext("2d");
var llocation = 600;
var length = 360;
var linewidth = 2;
var testInt = length/(linewidth*2);
var wColour = "#994c00";
function isEven(value) {
if (value%2 == 0)
    return true;
else
    return false;
}
for(i=0;i<testInt+1;i++){

    if(isEven(i)==true){
        var wColour = "#994c00";
    }
    else if(isEven(i)==false){
        var wColour = "#B87333";
    }

    ctx.beginPath();
    ctx.strokeStyle = wColour;
    ctx.lineWidth = linewidth;
    ctx.rect(llocation,300,length,250);
    ctx.stroke();
    ctx.closePath();
    var llocation = llocation + linewidth;
    var length = length - (linewidth*2);
}
```

Comment: Do you get any errors in the console?

Comment: Failed to load resource: net::ERR_FILE_NOT_FOUND

Comment: Note* When I remove the troubled function, the last function drawGround no longer works.

Comment: The other two functions execute.--- I'll add my html page code.

Comment: I managed to figure out the issue is not with the linking of the files. I will remove the HTML files and keep the main program.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Placement and order of javascript is important. At the simplest level javascript code is executed in the order it appears on the page. This means that if you have a function `function foo()` in a file `foo.js` and try to call it from a script above where you load the file `foo.js` it will fail because the function has not yet been loaded.

For the safest way put all your code at the bottom of the page just before the closing `</body>` tag with the files containing the function above the code that calls the functions.

The same goes for element that you access. If you are accessing the canvas element in script above where the canvas element is in the document, it will fail because the canvas element has not yet been loaded and does not exist.

Alternately you can use the document on load event to start you code. This will ensure that everything has been loaded and parsed ready for your code.

```
document.addEventListener("load",function(){
    // your code
});
```

Comment: I actually just found out that the order of the functions was not the problem. Sorry! There is just a syntax in the updated code. Thank You!

Comment: No problem, glad you got it sorted. BTW when I read your question the first time I noticed you had Javascript at the very top of the page. Just to let you know that putting code outside the `head` or `body` places your browser into whats called Quirks mode and will affect the performance of your code and the layout of the page. Best to keep the scripts in the right place.

Comment: Thanks, I still don't know the syntax error of the code in there now.

Comment: If that is all the code then you are missing the function `isEven()` use `if(i%2===0 ){ ` to test for even `%` means remainder. Also remove the var from the bottom two lines. The variable already exist and the var token will cause a error. Also you have `ctx.stroke()` befor `ctx.closePath()` Close path should come before stroke or it does nothing.

Comment: Hard for us to tell without all the code. Yo should use the dev tools. Hit F12 on the browser or goto settings and find "Dev tools"  Then find the `console` tab to view the console. Refresh the page and that will show you the error. Click on the page and line number on the right opposite the error and it will bring up the source on the line that has the error.